# Access private elements of object of same class

Tags: c++, class, private, private-members

Is this legal? If not, will the following code allow this?

```
class Foo
{
    friend class Foo;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That's redundant. Foo already has access to all Foo members. Two Foo objects can access each other's members.

```
class Foo {
public:
  int touchOtherParts(const Foo &foo) {return foo.privateparts;}
private:
  int privateparts;
};

Foo a,b;
b.touchOtherParts(a);
```

The above code will work just fine. B will access a's private data member.

Comment: @Alex: it's an old C++ pun, that C++ is probably the only language where one allow one's friends to touch one's private parts :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is legal for an object of class `Foo` to access the private members of another object of class `Foo`. This is frequently necessary for things like copy construction and assignment, and no special friend declaration is required.

Answer (score 3):

It is redundant and unnecessary. Moreover, I get the following warning in g++

```
warning: class ‘Foo’ is implicitly friends with itself
```

Answer (score 2):

Classes friending themselves makes sense if they're templates, as each instantiation with distinct parameters is a different class.